# Three-Column Group-By in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two different result sets:

```
Result 1:

+--------------+--------------+
| YEAR_MONTH   | UNIQUE_USERS |
+--------------+--------------+
|   2013-08    |     1111     |
+--------------+--------------+
|   2013-09    |     2222     |
+--------------+--------------+

Result 2:

+--------------+----------------+
| YEAR_MONTH   | UNIQUE_ACTIONS |
+--------------+----------------+
|   2013-08    |   111111111    |
+--------------+----------------+
|   2013-09    |   222222222    |
+--------------+----------------+
```

**The code for Result 1**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ACCESS_DATE, 'yyyy-mm') YEAR_MONTH, COUNT(DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_ID) UNIQUE_USERS
    FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ACCESS_DATE, 'yyyy-mm')
ORDER BY YEAR_MONTH ASC
```

**The code for Result 2**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ACCESS_DATE, 'yyyy-mm') YEAR_MONTH, COUNT(DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_ACTION) UNIQUE_ACTIONS
    FROM CORE.ACTION_TEST
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ACCESS_DATE, 'yyyy-mm')
ORDER BY YEAR_MONTH ASC
```

However, I've tried to group them by simply doing this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ACCESS_DATE, 'yyyy-mm') YEAR_MONTH, COUNT(DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_ID) UNIQUE_USERS, COUNT(DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_ACTION) UNIQUE_ACTIONS
    FROM CORE.DATE_TEST, CORE.ACTION_TEST
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ACCESS_DATE, 'yyyy-mm')
ORDER BY YEAR_MONTH ASC
```

And that doesn't work. I've also tried an `INNER JOIN` on the second result set (`result set 1` had `t1` as a variable name, and `result set 2` had `t2`), and got the error, `Invalid Identifier`, on t2.

This is my desired output:

```
+--------------+--------------+----------------+
| YEAR_MONTH   | UNIQUE_USERS | UNIQUE_ACTIONS |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+
|   2013-08    |     1111     |    111111111   |   
+--------------+--------------+----------------+
|   2013-09    |     2222     |    222222222   |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+
```

How do I do that correctly? It doesn't necessarily need to be a three-column group by; it just needs to work.

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN the two SELECT's including GROUP BY.

Comment: In PLSQL? I thought `FULL OUTER JOIN` was only supported by the SQL:1999 syntax?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware of that limitation.

Comment: This isn't PL/SQL.  It's just SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name keeps removing my 'plsql' tag. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, because your questions don't have any PL/SQL in them. They are plain SQL. PL/SQL is only used for stored procedures/functions or triggers. So unless you have a problem with a stored procedure (or an anonymous PL/SQL block) the `plsql` tag is incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select a.YEAR_MONTH, a.UNIQUE_USERS, b.UNIQUE_ACTIONS
from (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(ACCESS_DATE, 'yyyy-mm') YEAR_MONTH,
        COUNT(DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_ID) UNIQUE_USERS
    FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ACCESS_DATE, 'yyyy-mm')
) a
join (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(ACCESS_DATE, 'yyyy-mm') YEAR_MONTH,
        COUNT(DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_ACTION) UNIQUE_ACTIONS
    FROM CORE.ACTION_TEST
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ACCESS_DATE, 'yyyy-mm')
) b
on a.YEAR_MONTH = b.YEAR_MONTH
order by a.YEAR_MONTH ASC
```

Comment: Perfect! This is a million times faster than the solution below. I did not know you could do a select this way. Time to practice with this!

Comment: If a year/month combination appears in one table, but not in the other, then that year/month will be omitted from the results.

Answer (score 2):

If both tables have many records, a Cartesian join is a poor solution and may not actually provide the answer you want. I'd solve this problem something like this:

```
SELECT   TO_CHAR (COALESCE (t1.year_month, t2.year_month), 'yyyy-mm')
            AS year_month,
         t1.unique_users,
         t2.unique_actions
FROM     (SELECT   TRUNC (access_date, 'mm') AS year_month,
                   COUNT (DISTINCT employee_id) AS unique_users
          FROM     core.date_test
          GROUP BY TRUNC (access_date, 'mm')) t1
         FULL OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT   TRUNC (access_date, 'mm') AS year_month,
                   COUNT (DISTINCT employee_action) AS unique_actions
          FROM     core.action_test
          GROUP BY TRUNC (access_date, 'mm')) t2
            ON t1.year_month = t2.year_month
ORDER BY COALESCE (t1.year_month, t2.year_month) ASC
```

The reason a Cartesian join performs poorly is that every row in the first table must be matched with every row in the second table before the `group by` is applied. If each table has only 1000 rows, that's 1,000,000 values that the database has to construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT date.TO_CHAR(ACCESS_DATE, 'yyyy-mm') YEAR_MONTH, COUNT(DISTINCT date.EMPLOYEE_ID) UNIQUE_USERS, COUNT(DISTINCT act.EMPLOYEE_ACTION) UNIQUE_ACTIONS
    FROM CORE.DATE_TEST date, CORE.ACTION_TEST act
    WHERE date.TO_CHAR(ACCESS_DATE, 'yyyy-mm')=act.TO_CHAR(ACCESS_DATE, 'yyyy-mm')
    ORDER BY YEAR_MONTH ASC
```

Hope This will work as we need to specify the table name from where we want to extract the rows....